# How can I determine the revision of a calendar item in EWS when using a PullSubscription

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to do some synchronization work with and Exchange Calendar.  I want to keep another external calendar in sync with Exchange.  Currently when the other app triggers a creation or update of some sort in Exchange, that change is then sent back to the other calendar creating an endless loop.

I had hoped to use the AppointmentSequenceNumber property when binding the Appointment item, but it always has the value of 0 no matter how many times it is updated.  I am including AppointmentSequenceNumber in my PropertySet.

If anyone knows of a way to catch these updates and keep them from being sent back, that would be very helpful.

Thank you.

```
        PropertySet pSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.Body, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End,AppointmentSchema.ArchiveTag, AppointmentSchema.InstanceKey, AppointmentSchema.AppointmentSequenceNumber);
        ChangeCollection<ItemChange> changes = null;
        .....
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013)
        {
            Url = new Uri(exInfo.ServiceURL),
            Credentials = new WebCredentials(exInfo.UserName, exInfo.Password)
        };

        //Pull Subscription Info
        Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PullSubscription sub = service.SubscribeToPullNotifications(
            new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Calendar }, 30, "",
            EventType.Created, EventType.Modified, EventType.Deleted);
        syncState = exInfo.SyncState;
        //Pull Changes
        while (!syncComplete )//&& Count < MaxItems)
        {
            changes = service.SyncFolderItems(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar),
            PropertySet.FirstClassProperties, null, 100, SyncFolderItemsScope.NormalItems, syncState);

        foreach (ItemChange change in changes)
        {
            if (change.ChangeType != ChangeType.Delete) { eventItem = Appointment.Bind(service, change.ItemId, pSet); }
            switch (change.ChangeType)
            {
                case ChangeType.Update:
                   ...
                    break;
                case ChangeType.Create:
                    ...
                    break;
                case ChangeType.Delete:
                   ...
                    break;
            }    
            Count++;           
        }            
        syncState = changes.SyncState;
        syncComplete = !changes.MoreChangesAvailable;
        }...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AppointmentSequenceNumber would only be valid for Meetings; on normal Appointments it isn't used.

> I had hoped to use the AppointmentSequenceNumber property when binding the Appointment item

That wouldn't work even if it was incrementing. Exchange will always provide you with the current version and the only things valid in a Bind is the EWSId of the appointment (or the Recurrence Sequence).

> If anyone knows of a way to catch these updates and keep them from being sent back, that would be very helpful.

Synchronization is complicated but (from a notification perspective) if you modify an item in Exchange it's going to fire a notification and the ChangeKey attribute on the Item will be updated ([quote](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605828(v=exchg.150).aspx)):

*"When you work with items in Exchange, another value to keep in mind is the ChangeKey attribute. This value, in addition to the item ID, is used to keep track of the state of an item. Any time an item is changed, a new change key is generated. When you perform an UpdateItem operation, for example, you can use the ChangeKey attribute to let the server know that your update is being applied to the most current version of the item. If another application made a change to the item you’re updating, the change keys won’t match and you will not be able to perform the update."*